# Identify non-duplicates and copy to new column on Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, if

I have a set of two columns. Column F has a list of names of scheduled attendees. Column C uses Match & Index to pull up attendees name when they scan their badge onto column A. I am interested in columns C and F.

Using conditional formatting "unique" on columns C and F, I can identify walk-ins as the name that will be pulled up on column C won't be on my scheduled list on Column F.

I am looking to find a formula rather than using macros to pull up the walk ins (the values that are not duplicates) onto a separate column named "walk ins").

Advanced Filter as well as formula "unique" can not work in this case since I am looking for values that appear just once. Why? Because if "John" appears on both column C & F, then the advanced filter and unique formula will record a single "John" as a unique value. But my interest for that matter is not in John who appears on both columns but on Paul who is pulled up on column C but is not on column F.

In short - I need to identify "non-duplicates or single values" not unique values.

Thanks very much in advance.

---

Most of you have gotten an understanding of what I am looking for but to remove any misunderstandings, I have included an example. In the real life, I manually record the walk-ins in a column on another worksheet of same workbook.

[Example of what I am looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjRJ3.png)

Comment: An example of your data (preferably as a table that can be copy/pasted) and your desired output would be useful in helping you craft a solution. (*The data doesn't have to be real; but should be representative of your real data*)

Comment: By the way, the `UNIQUE` function does have an argument to return only single items. But that wouldn't help as you would have a single item if a registrant did not attend. I think, more accurately, you need to find entries in column C that do not appear in Column F

Comment: Hello @Ron Rosenfield. I have accepted the answer because I believe this is what I am looking for. I am fairly good at excel but this is too intricate for me. However although I am running out of time, I am determined to understand and crack it. Question: do I have to place the formula on first cell of the column where I want walk ins to be then the formula will auto fill the rest of cells? An am amateur to sequence and aggregate, I would appreciate any tip you provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. In my example, it is in `H2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Office 365 Excel, you can generate a list of walk-ins using:

```
=LET(x,1/ISNA(MATCH(Attendees,Scheduled,0))*ROW(Attendees),y,AGGREGATE(15,6,x,SEQUENCE(COUNT(x)))-1,INDEX(Attendees,y))
```

`Attendees` and `Scheduled` refer to the obvious ranges.

[image]

If you have earlier versions, a more complicated formula will work, but it would be helpful to know which version of Excel you are working with.

One possibility would be:

```
=INDEX(Attendees,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNA(MATCH(Attendees,Scheduled,0))*ROW(Attendees)-1,ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(1/ISNA(MATCH(Attendees,Scheduled,0))*ROW(Attendees))))))
```

which you may or may not have to "confirm" as an **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

Please note that in both formulas, the `-1` (as in `AGGREGATE(...)-1` is to adjust for the header row of the defined range so as to be able to use the `INDEX` function.  The `INDEX` function looks at position in the array; whereas `ROW` looks at the absolute row number of the location.  If your ranges started in other than `Row 1`, you would adjust that factor accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I believe this is what I am looking for. I am on Office 365. This is a brilliant formula but could you please walk me through if you can of only just one cell because I have no clue where 15,6,1 come from or either -1 or even x, y. This is very crucial to work I am currently doing so will be a game changer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Truly, brilliant answer!

Comment: @TeodrosIV I have added an explanation of the `-1` to my answer.  So far as the `15,16,1,x`, please examine Excel help for the `AGGREGATE` and `LET` functions. Pretty well explained there.

Comment: @TeodrosIV By the way, since my answer seems to satisfy your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your description I made this data:

[image]

Paul walked in, while others scheduled their attendance. (Column `A` is not important.)

---

I think **the easiest way would be using `MATCH`**. E.g., in `D2` you could use something like this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(C2,F:F,0),"scheduled"),"WALK IN")
```

[image]c

---

As another approach, you could put **conditional formatting** formula on column `C`:

```
=AND(NOT(IFERROR(MATCH(C1,F:F,0),0)),C1<>"", C1<>"attendees")
```

[image]

---

As you insist, this is the **formula for a separate column containing unique values** (only Paul in this case).

This is an array formula (array formulas are entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of usual Enter).

Array formulas do not work in Excel table objects and they best perform when a specific range is supplied instead of a full column (because they would actually do calculations on every cell in that whole column of 1 million rows). So, since a specific range is preferable, the maintenance of such formulas can be pain.

For this formula to work, an additional column is also required. I mean, the "walk ins" column described in the first alternative above. So, in total you will have 2 additional columns if you choose this alternative.

If you still want to do it, here's the formula:

```
=IFERROR(
   INDEX(
      $C$2:$C$5,
      SMALL(
         IF(
            $D$2:$D$5<>"WALK IN",
            "",
            ROW($D$2:$D$5)-MIN(ROW($D$2:$D$5))+1),
         ROW(D2)-1)),
   "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I am currently looking to have a different column that has walk ins but will seriously consider this as a possibility. Thank you

Comment: Please take a look at the last alternative. It does what you want, but it may have some drawbacks which I listed. Be aware if you decide to choose the formula.